# how to use all cpu cores to train model in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I read that keras will automatically use all available cores in my cpu.
But my one does not seems to do so.
I use google platform's Jupyter notebook.
I tried the virtual machine with 8 core, 16 core and 32 core.
But training speed is same(or at least I can not see any difference).
I wonder how can I use all cpu cores to train the model?

Comment: Your results do **not** mean that multiple cores are not being used, it means that computation is not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- GPUs has 10^3 cores. That's 100 times more than a CPU has.
- The bandwith between those cores is much larger and faster compared to a CPU
- They also have faster and larger memory to store data and intermediate results.

A x2, x4 or even x10 upgrade on your CPU will not yield significative improvements.